# Nested redundant 'if' conditions

Tags: c++, c, if-statement

Is there a better (or cleaner) way to write the following code?

```
if(conditionX)
{
    if(condition1)
    {
        // code X1
    }
    else if(condition2)
    {
        // code X2
    }
}
else if(conditionY)
{
    if(condition1)
    {
        // code Y1
    }
    else if(condition2)
    {
        // code Y2
    }
}
```

I have a few more conditions, but I guess you get the point.

Comment: Not enough information for me. If there is a way you can achieve your target then better use an enum. How come so many upvotes to the question though (O_o)~!

Comment: I don't see any *redundant* `if`s there.

Comment: Please don't mind, but -1, because I see no real question here.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are four approaches to this problem, none of which is universal:

1. **Leave everything as is** - There isn't much code duplication here. If computing `condition1` and `condition2` is tricky, compute them upfront and store them in `bool` variables
2. **Make `conditionX` and `conditionY` produce a result that lets you unify `condition1` and `condition2`** - This is not always possible, but in some situations you could prepare a variable that unifies the activities taken in the two branches, say, by using a function pointer or a lambda.
3. **Put the processing logic into subclasses with virtual functions to eliminate conditional logic** - This is possible only when your initial design missed an opportunity to subclass. Essentially, this approach pushes the decision on `conditionX`/`conditionY` into a place where a subclass is created, and then "reuses" that decision later on by calling a proper override of a virtual function in the interface.
4. **Create a numeric combination representing all three conditions, and convert to `switch`** - This trick unifies the conditionals, reducing the nesting.

Here is an example of the last approach:

```
int caseNumber = ((conditionX?1:0) << 3)
               | ((conditionY?1:0) << 2)
               | ((condition2?1:0) << 1)
               | ((condition1?1:0) << 0);
switch (caseNumber) {
    case 0x09:
    case 0x0D:
    case 0x0F: // code X1
        break;
    case 0x0A:
    case 0x0E: // code X2
        break;
    case 0x05:
    case 0x07: // code Y1
        break;
    case 0x06: // code Y2
        break;
}
```

Comment: Unless the `caseNumber`s *mean* something, the third approach is clearly worse than the original. IMVHO, at least.

Comment: @vonbrand The last approach is useful for situations when you need to cover all or nearly all combinations. A chain of `if`s is OK with only four conditions, but once you get to five or six, a flat structure with meaningless numbers and lots of comments beats multi-way nesting for readability purposes.

Comment: I agree the switch can be better than deeply nested, repetitive conditions, but I also agree you want meaningful case labels. See the answer from barak manos for a better way to represent the cases so you can see which conditions they correspond to

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: You are not handling case 0x7 (Code-Y1), case 0xB (Code-X1), case 0xD (Code-X1), case 0xE (Code-X2), and case 0xF (Code-X1). All of this, is due to the fact that `conditionX == true` does not necessarily mean that `conditionY == false`, and vice-versa. The same goes to `condition1` and `condition2`.

Answer (score 25):

If your concern is with clean code in terms of viewing the source, my advice would be to segregate the blocks into their own sections, something like:

```
if      (conditionX) processConditionX();
else if (conditionY) processConditionY();
```

and so on.

Then, in the sub-functions, you place the "meat":

```
void processConditionX (void) {
    if(condition1) {
        // code X1
    } else if(condition2) {
        // code X2
    }
}
```

You can modify it to pass in and return parameters as necessary and I'd make the conditions and function names a little more descriptive, though I assume they're just examples here.

Answer (score 14):

You can implement a state-machine instead:

```
#define COMBINATION(a,b,c,d) (((a)<<3)|((b)<<2)|((c)<<1)|((d)<<0))

switch (COMBINATION(conditionX,conditionY,condition1,condition2))
{
    case COMBINATION(0,0,0,0):           break;
    case COMBINATION(0,0,0,1):           break;
    case COMBINATION(0,0,1,0):           break;
    case COMBINATION(0,0,1,1):           break;
    case COMBINATION(0,1,0,0):           break;
    case COMBINATION(0,1,0,1): CodeY2(); break;
    case COMBINATION(0,1,1,0): CodeY1(); break;
    case COMBINATION(0,1,1,1): CodeY1(); break;
    case COMBINATION(1,0,0,0):           break;
    case COMBINATION(1,0,0,1): CodeX2(); break;
    case COMBINATION(1,0,1,0): CodeX1(); break;
    case COMBINATION(1,0,1,1): CodeX1(); break;
    case COMBINATION(1,1,0,0):           break;
    case COMBINATION(1,1,0,1): CodeX2(); break;
    case COMBINATION(1,1,1,0): CodeX1(); break;
    case COMBINATION(1,1,1,1): CodeX1(); break;
}
```

This includes only one branch operation, so it is possibly a little more efficient (even though it also includes an additional runtime computation (at the `switch` line)).

As to being cleaner, I guess it's a matter of perspective, but the template above also gives you a convenient way to detect all unhandled branches within your code.

Please note that if **any** of the condition variables may have a value other than 1 or 0, then you should:

```
#define COMBINATION(a,b,c,d) (((a)?8:0)|((b)?4:0)|((c)?2:0)|((d)?1:0))
```

**Update (attributed to @Jonathan Wakely in one of the comments below):**

If you're using C++11, then you may replace the `COMBINATION` macro with a `constexpr` function:

```
constexpr int COMBINATION(bool a,bool b,bool c,bool d)
{
    return ((int)a<<3) | ((int)b<<2) | ((int)c<<1) | ((int)d<<0);
}
```

Comment: `COMBINATION` should be a constexpr function, not a macro

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely: Why? I would prefer to have as many computations as possible during compile-time (or preprocess-time).

Comment: Yes. That's what a `constexpr` function is for. Macros suck. In C you have no choice, unfortunately, but in C++11 a constexpr function is preferable for many reasons (clearer, type-safe, written using C++ syntax not the error-prone preprocessor). For example if `conditionX` is an `int` with value 15 then your macro does the wrong thing. `constexpr condX(bool b) { return int(b) << 3; }` wouldn't have that problem, the value is converted to `true` first, then can only produce the correct value after shifting it

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely: Thanks for teaching me something I didn't know :) ... OP tagged this question as `C` and `C++`, so I'm not sure which one is being used. I added an update to my answer (based on your description) in any case...

Answer (score 6):

I would provide the decision inside the first if as a parameter to a separated functions which then decides which code to execute, like:

```
if(conditionX)
{
    Method1(Condition Parameters)
}
else if(conditionY)
{
    Method1(Condition Parameters)
}
```

Another way would be to provide all needed info to a decision method (matrix), this method returns an integer which you use in a switch statement to decide which code to execute. In this way you separate the desicion logic which makes it readable and easy to unittest if needed:

```
DecisionMatrix(conditionX, conditionY, condition1, condition2)
{
  //  return a value according to the conditions for Example:
  // CoditionX + Condition1 => return 1
  // CoditionX + Condition2 => return 2
  // CoditionY + Condition1 => return 3
  // CoditionY + Condition2 => return 4
}

switch(DecisionMatrix)
{
    case 1: //run code X1       
    break;
    case 2: //run code X2
    break;
    case 3: //run code Y1       
    break;
    case 4: //run code Y2
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. The best way here would be to use polymorphism **(Only if the chunks of code are huge)**
2. If they are small code snippets, creating classes would obviously be an overkill.

   Therefore, if there is similarity in all codes, I'd suggest a seemingly easy but really difficult task.

   - Try to parametrize them as much as you can.
   - Create a function that takes those and call them in the conditions
   - Now the code would be in function blocks and "cleaner"

It is always difficult to create simple things.

```
if (conditionX) {
    method(parameterX);
else if (conditionY) {
    method(parameterY);
}
```

where

```
void method(ParameterType e) {
    if (condition 1) {
        // Code in terms of parameter e
    } else if (condition2) {
        // Code in terms of parameter e
    }
}
```

The condition that you can parametrize should be kept outside.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I think this way can be another way for solving your code.

```
enum ConditionParentType
{
    CONDITION_NONE = 0,
    CONDITION_X,
    CONDITION_Y,
};

enum ConditionChildType
{
    CONDITION_0 = 0,
    CONDITION_1,
    CONDITION_2,
};

class ConditionHandler
{
public:
    explicit ConditionHandler(ConditionParentType p_type, ConditionChildType c_type) 
        : p_type_(p_type), c_type_(c_type) {};
    void DoAction()
    {
        if(child_type == CONDITION_1)
        {

        }
        else if(child_type == CONDITION_2)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            //error
        }
    }

private:
    const ConditionParentType p_type_;
    const ConditionChildType  c_type_;
}; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    ConditionParentType parent_type = GetParentType();
    ConditionChildType  child_type  = GetChildType();

    ConditionHandler handler(parent_type, child_type);
    handler.DoAction();

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never have I seen so much encapsulation going into writing if statements. This is a bit much

Answer (score 3):

If the combination of conditions means something then I'd write a set simple methods that return boolean values. You would end up with something like:

```
  if (first-condition(conditionX, condition1)) {
    // code X1
  } else if (first-condition(conditionX, condition2)) {
    // code X2
  } else if (third-condition(conditionY, condition1)) {
    // code Y1
  } else if (fourth-condition(conditionY, condition2)) {
    // code Y2
  }
```

The names of the methods describe the conditions. Don't worry that the methods are only called once (the compiler will probably in-line them anyway), the important bit it that your code then becomes self documenting.

Comment: But, if the condition ended up being, say, the 4th, this would give you a decrease in performance. This method of yours would have iterated through 4 if statements whereas the original poster's method would only go through 3 if statements. It doesn't sound a lot, but if there were far more conditions, the performance decrease could be substantial.

Comment: It very much depends upon exactly what the conditions are. I'm making the assumption that that are going to be fairly simple expressions which will therefore be quick to evaluate. This may not be true (and the question doesn't say), but it usually is the case. For this question skipping a single condition sounds like premature optimisation which can often make code slower! IMHO It's far better to have clarity of source code as this makes the the job of the maintenance engineer (typically me!) easier and less error prone. I could go on, but I'm getting off topic.

Answer (score 3):

I'm quite surprised by the other suggested answers, which are mostly wrong if:

- The two repeated conditions `condition1` or `condition2` are complex, in which case [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) comes into play, or
- Any of the four conditions have side effects, or
- Any of the conditions are slow (for example, find the minimum of a large array, or read a file), or
- A boolean short-circuit is needed, as in: `if (p == 0) {...} else if (p->foo == 42) {...}`.

If none of these hold, as is the case 99.42% of the time, then leave the code as it is. Or, as a minor variation, change it so the nesting (that is, indentation) is only one level, not two.

Otherwise, you will need to use temporary variables as follows

```
const bool tstX =         (conditionX);    
const bool tstY = tstX || (conditionY);    
const bool tst1 = tstY && (condition1);
const bool tst2 = tstY && !tst1 && (condition2);
```

Answer (score 1):

the original code doesn't look to bad. Depending on the specific case it may or may not be more readable to do something like:

```
if(conditionX and condition1) {
  // code X1
} 
else if(conditionX and condition2) {
  // code X2
}
else if(conditionY and condition1) {
  // code Y1
}
else if(conditionY and condition2)
  // code Y2
}
```