# Using C macro to nicely combine two options in code

Tags: c, macros, kernel, driver, alsa

I have some ALSA driver code that has many lines that have to change for going between two audio configurations: L/R stereo and mono, but I would like a single switch to choose between L/R mode or just mono mode. I currently have two files, one for L/R and one for mono, but the disadvantage is both files have to be maintained with the same updates. It would be nice to have everything in one file since so much is similar between the two.

For example:

L/R Stereo:

```
regmap_read(WM88->regmapL, addr, &val_l);
regmap_read(WM88->regmapR, addr, &val_r);
pr_info("%s: reg 0x%02X, val_l 0x%02X, val_r 0x%02X\n",
__func__, addr, val_l, val_r);
```

Mono:

```
regmap_read(WM88->regmapL, addr, &val_l);
pr_info("%s: reg 0x%02X, val_l 0x%02X\n",
__func__, addr, val_l);
```

One option is to have a bunch of #ifdef #endif blocks, but it looks pretty ugly. Is there a better way to do this? It doesn't have to be a macro, but I thought that might be the best method.

Comment: maybe this can be usefull http://stackoverflow.com/q/22479162/2549281

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified C:

Put the code for each configuration into a separate subroutine.

Create an array of function pointers (in this case with two elements, one for Stereo and one for Mono). Name it something like "FunctionArray"

Use the currently selected configuration to create an integer offset into the array (0 or 1). Name it something like "ConfigurationIndex"

In the main call the function given by FunctionArray[ConfigurationIndex].

This is basically a fancy 'if' statement but it allows you to add as many different options as you like.