# C++ switch regex cases

Tags: c++, regex, switch-statement

I would like to use `switch case` to determine my value with `regex`, but it seems that I can't do this way. I can use `regex` successfully with `if else`, like below:

```
if (regex_search(dic_char, lowercase)) {
    cout << dic_char << endl;
} else if (regex_search(dic_char, uppercase)) {
    // do something
} else {
    cout << "Not characters." << endl;
}
```

but I want to do in this way:

```
switch (dic_char) {
    case regex_search(dic_char, lowercase):
        cout << dic_char << endl;
        break;
    case regex_search(dic_char, uppercase):
        // do something
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Not characters." << endl;
        break;
}
```

Does anyone know how I do in this way ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `switch()` only operates on integer numeric primitives!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for your reply, so I shouldn't use it to determine my `char` or `string`.

Comment: single `char` is a integer numeric primitive, but `case` must use a constant expression (which `regex_search(dic_char, uppercase)` isn't.

Comment: Thanks, I know, so it's not allowed to use `switch` for `char array` and `string`. I only can use it with `if else` ?

Comment: You can't really use `switch` in your case.

Comment: Yes, `if() {} else if()` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it (although most likely not feasible in your case):

Rewrite function `regex_search` as a macro (consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22479857/1382251) as an example).

A `switch` statement in C and C++ can only take constant values as cases.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do your calculation outside the switch statement and use the resulting value to switch on.

In your particular case, it doesn't make much sense, since there are only two choices anyway.

But a more general pattern would be:

```
result = do_calculation(p1,p2,..)

switch(result) {

   case 1: ...
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if-else` version and the `switch-case` version you provided are logically different. In the former the condition is on the return value of `regex_search()` method while in later form the condition is on the value of `dic_char'. To write`switch-case` version equivalent to the former you can you following :

```
   int res = regex_search(param); ///this method must return int/convertible to int value
   switch(res)
   {
      case ... 
   }
```

You can create an `enum` containing the valid return values from the method and use it in case statement.